# Custom role class name in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, role

I've been reviewing this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Note how it says "This will create the acme_role table and a user_role that stores the many-to-many relationship between acme_user and acme_role...".

How can I define the name of this table? I don't want user_role, I want it to be called "application_name_user_roles".

Also, I would prefer my entity names to match table names, so instead of Role.php and a class called Role, I'd like it to be UserPermission.php with UserPermission as the class name.

How can I enforce these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name your entities whatever you like, it is only important that it implements valid interfaces (i.e. `UserInterface` for user class. Then you pass YOUR class names to `security.yml` and all should work perfectly.

Comment: When I tried calling changing "Role" to "UserPermission", and running php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force it said "The target-entity MyApp\Entity\Role cannot be found in 'MyApp\Entity\User#roles'". Any ideas?

Comment: apart from file name and class name you need to change mapping info, so every occurence of `Role` in your annotations must be changed (look after `@ORM` tag)

Comment: Thanks, I had missed the class name in "@ORM\ManyToMany". That fixed it. Do you know what I could do to change the name of the table that gets generated? I don't want "user_role", I want to be able to name this table to match my existing naming scheme.Thanks

Comment: Okay, almost there... I just had to add @ORM\JoinTable(name="application_name_user_roles"). Only one minor problem remains... the column created is called userpermission_id. Obviously it's just using the class name appended by _id... even though in my entity I have clearly defined the ID column to be "user_permission_id". Any ideas how I can ensure the right name is being used?

Comment: you can pass `name` parameter to column: `@ORM\Column(name="your_column_name")`.